# Secure way of exchanging email addresses (hashing) to allow matching for overlap on another list, but not reveal those for which there is no overlap?

Tags: security, encryption, sha1, salt

I'm with an organization (Company A) that has a large email list.  I'm sending a 10,000 email subset of this list to another organization (Company B) to test for overlap (discover which email addresses are on both lists).  I want to send the list in a way that is easy for Company B to test for overlap, but difficult (ideally impossible) for Company B to "decode" the email addresses which are NOT already on their list.  Secondarily, I want to ensure that if the list I send winds up in the wrong hands (some 3rd party), it would be difficult for anyone else to learn the actual email addresses on the list.

My current solution is to simply pull the emails from our database as

```
SHA1(email + a_long_random_salt)
```

Using the same salt for each email address.

To do the match, I send the list of hashes and the salt (securely, separately) to Company B, and they simply search their database using

```
SELECT email FROM members WHERE SHA1(email + the_salt) IN(hash1, hash2, hash3....)
```

(Or they pre-compute the SHA1 hash for each address and store it in the DB with the email address so the hashing doesn't need to happen as the query is run)

A sufficiently long/random salt prevents against use of a precomputed rainbow table to crack the hashes.  I assume it to be rather unlikely that anyone has a rainbow table of millions upon millions of plausible email addresses salted with whatever 100 character random string I use as my salt. As long as the salt is kept secret, no 3rd party is going to decode this list with a rainbow table or brute force.  (Please, correct me if I'm somehow wrong here.)

The issue that I'm struggling with is there are obviously easily-obtained lists of millions upon millions of email addresses harvested from the web.  It would be pretty easy for Company B to obtain one of these lists, compute the hashes using the salt I've provided, and recover some significant portion of emails on the list I've sent (certainly not all, but a significant portion).

Is there some strategy to accomplish this match that I'm failing to come up with?  The only thing I can think of is to use a more complex hashing method (i.e. multiple iterations) to make it **slower** to match against a list of hundreds of millions of email addresses (that theoretical list scraped from the web).  The key is that it would really only be **slower** -- not really even **difficult**.  Also, I know that Company B's own email list is in the range of 1 million addresses, so I can't give them a hashing scheme that would take many seconds to compute for each address on that list of 1 million.  Simply making it slower doesn't solve the issue -- I think I need a completely different approach.

Honestly, this particular case this is more of an academic exercise for me than a real security concern.  I trust Company B is not going to try to do this (we work together often), and even if they did it would be no huge loss.  All they could possibly learn is email addresses of 10,000 people on our mailing list -- we're not talking about passwords, credit card numbers, etc.  If we were dealing with passwords or credit card numbers, I wouldn't even be considering developing some scheme of my own.  And, yes, of course I realize that SHA-256 or some other newer algorithm might be a bit preferable to SHA1, but only to some very limited extent.  It's not a brute force crack of the hash that I'm worried about here.

Comment: I should add that any solution needs to be relatively straightforward to implement.  It can't be something that takes more than an hour or two to set up.  And learning that there simply is no practical way of doing what I'm asking would be equally useful if that's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can conduct the exchange as a Secure Multi-Party Computation problem - with the goal of computing the unique email addresses.

Quoting Wikipedia

> Secure multi-party computation (also
>   known as secure computation or
>   multi-party computation (MPC)) is a
>   sub field of cryptography. The goal of
>   methods for secure multi-party
>   computation is to enable parties to
>   jointly compute a function over their
>   inputs, while at the same time keeping
>   these inputs private.

If you visit the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multiparty_computation
There "external links" section contains libraries and references to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is a brute force attack on known domains. Consider the following factors:

- @hotmail.com, @gmail.com and @yahoo.com have a great share of the market
- the list of last names is finite and not too long. The same for the list of first names

Taking the combination of the name John and surname Doe, we can construct a set of addresses like JDoe@hotmail.com, DoeJ@yahoo.com, JohnDow@hotmail.com etc. The set won't be very extensive.

Depending on how important / benefitial such data mining is (i.e. how much will B gain from knowing that John Doe is in your list), attack that I described can still be profitable. Yes, I remember about salts, but still the number of name/domain combinations is not too large to be unbreakable for good parallel brute force attack.

Comment: Yes, definitely taking that into consideration.  Similar to fact that it's not difficult to acquire huge lists of email addresses that have been scraped from the web.  Part of the reason that I think any solution which tells "Company B" exactly how I computed the hashes is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your problem can be restated as:

> Company B has access to a list of 1
>   million email address, List A.  They
>   also have access to different list of
>   several million email addresses, List
>   B.  I would like Company B to be able
>   to run an algorithm to be able to
>   determine which of the email addresses
>   in List A is also on our list, but
>   *not* be able to run that algorithm against List B.

Re-stated like that, it appears to be a logical impossibility - there is really no difference between their customer database and a list of email addresses they may have downloaded elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed, it's not possible using methods I'm familiar with (giving them a list of hashed emails and the method for hashing them).  Answer from Colin, however, suggests there may be a different way to do it.

Comment: @Jase: I don't think so.  Even using that method, since the other company is keeping their inputs private, you can't tell if they're just feeding in their own customer list, or feeding in a list they've downloaded elsewhere.